# Is the Authorization header sensitive information?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I joined a friend's web application project, and my task at the moment is to check the security.

Is it possible to access a URL that returns a JSON of the call via API, in this case, in this JSON there is an `authHeader` parameter and its content, in this case it is in base64, but by doing the decode I get the info in the format `xxxx:xxxxxxxx` Since the first info is always numeric.

I couldn't authenticate using this authHeader, it always results in this error (using node):

```json
{
  code: -1102,
  msg: "Mandatory parameter 'signature' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."
}
```

So, if a `signature` is necessary, an `apiKey` and an `apiSecret` are also necessary, so isn't the `authHeader` sensitive information?

The last code I used to test is this (node):

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const authHeader = "Basic " + Buffer.from("xxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
const url = 'https://api.site.com/api/v3/account';

fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': authHeader
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Is it possible for someone to take advantage of this publicly available `authHeader` to obtain some type of access or any sensitive information from a user?

Is `authHeader` sensitive information that should not be made publicly available? If not, how someone could use the `authHeader`?

Comment: The `Authorization` header typically contains a username/password pair or other security credentials. Yes these are highly sensitive.

Comment: `this publicly available authHeader` How is it publicly available? Where is it? Is it hardcoded somewhere?

Comment: "*the info in the format `xxxx:xxxxxxxx`*" - what is the meaning/actual content of those xs?

Comment: "*my task at the moment is to check the security*" - you can check for best practices, but if this a real web application, you may want to hire an expert

Comment: @AdamJenkins It is a NTF platform that is about to be launched, there is a URL that displays information of the pool via api, so in this api data, it is displayed information about the owner of the asset, and it is included the authHeader in question.

Comment: @WiseHipoppotamus If asset owners are considered public information, this doesn't sound sensitive. And there is nothing wrong about including an owner identification in an  auth header either; it seems the actual security is added by *signing* those auth headers to make them unforgeable. However, these are just guesses based on the info your provided in the question, there should be an actual security model document outlining all of this, including the auth scheme and the sensitivity of information.

Comment: There's something missing here. If the API requires a signature, that indicates there's a secret somewhere. As long as the secret isn't exposed in the client source code or some client side storage (other than in memory), I'm going to guess that the auth header alone isn't sufficient. But that's a complete guess with no warranty implied. There's really not enough information in this question around the API or the security of the API to comment on whether your current implementation is secure or not.

Comment: @WiseHipoppotamus If this is for a serious NFT platform that you expect to earn money with (or even just with the potential to lose money), I repeat my recommendation to hire a security expert or you'll be robbed quicker than you can look.

Comment: @Bergi I don't know if it is a username / password, the first info is always numeric, in this case this is displayed 3 times in 3 URLs, so its like 5643687:dgfhfghmç$54dfgd  -- The second info its like a password.

Comment: @WiseHipoppotamus "*its like a password*" - you'll need to figure out what exactly it is - a password, a token, a hash of a password? However, nothing that resembles a password should ever be available for any other users than the one it belongs to.

Comment: @AdamJenkins Yes, that's the point, i want know if the authHeader alone it is enough for someone to have some type of restricted access or some sensitive information from a user, in the displayed front end there is no type of key or secret, only the authHeader.

Comment: @WiseHipoppotamus - if you can't use the auth header alone to access resources, and the other elements that are required for actual authorization aren't publicly exposed, then it's fine. It's a little odd it's passed as an `Authorization` header if it doesn't authorize a request. It really doesn't sound like you should be making these judgement calls, with or without the help of people on SO. Do you have access to the API code? What is actually required to authorize an API call (sounds like there's something else other than the authorization header, and it seems like it might be a signature)?

Comment: @Evert You were right, it's about credentials, the first part (numeric) is the Account ID and the other part is the password, I didn't associate it directly because the means of logging in are by email and telephone, even though I already have almost 100% sure the second part was the password. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, thank you very much for everyone's help, I was able to prove that this is indeed sensitive information.

As I said in the question after doing the decode, the information has this format: `xxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxx` and the first value is always numeric, because it is a number i did not directly associate with any credential, even though the second value seemed a lot like a password to me, as I said in the comments.

Considering what @Evert said: "The authorization header typically contains a username/password pair or other security credentials. Yes, they are highly confidential." I focused on credentials and discovered that the first value (numeric) refers to the `Account ID`, and the second value to the `password`, so if some attacker has access to this he can find some way, to associate that `Account ID` with some `email`, through Social Engineering or phishing for example, after that it would be enough to log in.

So yes, this is highly sensible.